# How to find the sublist containing a specific element in python3 without defining a function?

Tags: python-3.x, list

In a list of sublists,

```
lst = [[2,4,5,6], [0,1,3,7], [], ... , [8,9], [10, 11,12]]
```

find the sublist that has a specific element, say 9:

(Knowing that all elements are unique)

```
output: [8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask for the `next` sublist in the list if 9 is in the sublist with `None` if it is not found:

```
lst = [[2,4,5,6], [0,1,3,7], [],  [8,9], [10, 11,12]]

next((l for l in lst if 9 in l), None)
# [8, 9]
```